# iOS Issue : IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: codenameone

I'm facing an issue with iOS. 
I have an App who works perfectly on Android. I build it for Android Debug and when i try to show my form, i got an **IndexOutOfBoundsException**
Here is my code  :

```
package com.idenovia.calendovia.form;

public class FichePro extends Form {

    public static Site site;
    public static Boolean isFavorite = false;
    public static List<Performance> performances = new ArrayList<Performance>();
    public static Long canContactTakeEvent;
    public FichePro(final int idPro,final String searchWho, final List<Site> savedSites){

        try {
            Dialog ip = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
            ip.getContentPane().getStyle().setBgTransparency(0, true);
            ip.getContentPane().getComponentAt(0).getStyle().setBgTransparency(0, true);
            Map<String,Object> result;
            if(CalendoviaApp.isConnected ==1 && CalendoviaApp.customer.getId() != 0)
                result = AccessSite.getSiteFromId(idPro,CalendoviaApp.customer.getId());
            else
                result = AccessSite.getSiteFromId(idPro,0);
            if(result.containsKey("sites")){
                site = (Site) result.get("sites");
            }else{
                site = null;
            }
            if(result.containsKey("performances")){
                performances = (List<Performance>) result.get("performances");
            }else{
                performances = null;
            }
            if(result.containsKey("canContactTakeEvent")){
                canContactTakeEvent = (Long) result.get("canContactTakeEvent");
            }else{
                canContactTakeEvent = null;
            }
            ip.dispose();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
         * Form theming and configuring
         */
        if(site != null)
            setTitle("Dr. "+site.getSiteYou().getShowname());
        else{
            SearchList searchList = new SearchList(searchWho,"",savedSites);
            searchList.show();
        }
        Container content = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        content.setUIID("ctrContent");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFade(200));
        final Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("CALENDOVIA_APP", "CALENDOVIA_APP.ttf");
        Container ctrPhoto = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        ctrPhoto.setUIID("ctrPhoto");
        //              try {
        Image image = CalendoviaApp.res.getImage("placeholderProvider").scaled((int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.25),(int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.25));
        for (Site favoris : CalendoviaApp.favorites) {
            if(favoris.getId().equals(site.getId())){
                isFavorite = true;
            }
        }

        final CheckBox favButton2 = new CheckBox();
        final Button favButton = new Button();
        if(isFavorite){
            favButton.setIcon(FontImage.createFixed("\ue900", fnt, 0x2995d0,(int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.2), (int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.2)));
        }else{
            favButton.setIcon(FontImage.createFixed("\ue931", fnt, 0x2995d0,(int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.2), (int)(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()*0.2)));
        }
        favButton.setTextPosition(Component.BOTTOM);
        favButton.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0,true);
        favButton.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(0,true);
        favButton.getDisabledStyle().setBgTransparency(0,true);
        favButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if(isFavorite){
                    do some stuff like seticon or network access
                    }else{
                    do some stuff too
                }
            }
        });
        ctrPhoto.add(BorderLayout.WEST, image);
        ctrPhoto.add(BorderLayout.EAST, favButton);

        Container ctrglobalInfosFichePro = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ctrglobalInfosFichePro.setScrollVisible(false);
        ctrglobalInfosFichePro.setScrollableY(true);
        ctrglobalInfosFichePro.setUIID("ctrglobalInfosFichePro");

        //First Part
        Container ctrglobalInfosFirstPart = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ctrglobalInfosFirstPart.setScrollableY(false);
        ctrglobalInfosFirstPart.setUIID("ctrglobalInfosFirstPart");

        Label lblProviderName = new Label("Dr "+site.getSiteYou().getShowname());
        lblProviderName.setUIID("lblNameProvider");
        ctrglobalInfosFichePro.add(lblProviderName);
        try{
            Label lblProviderSpe = new Label(new SectorConvert().getValue(site.getSiteYou().getSectorfirst().intValue()).toString());
            lblProviderSpe.setUIID("lblSpeProvider");
            ctrglobalInfosFichePro.add(lblProviderSpe);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }     if(site.getSiteOption().getCbcard()||site.getSiteOption().getCheckp()||site.getSiteOption().getSpecies()){
            Label lblPaiement = new Label("MOYENS DE PAIEMENT");
            lblPaiement.setUIID("lblTitleForSpanLabel");
            lblPaiement.setVerticalAlignment(Component.CENTER);

            String acceptedPaiement ="";
            if(site.getSiteOption().getCbcard()){
                acceptedPaiement+=" CB /";
            }
            Label lblAcceptedPaiement = new Label(acceptedPaiement);
            ctrglobalInfosFirstPart.add(lblPaiement);
            ctrglobalInfosFirstPart.add(lblAcceptedPaiement);
        }

        //Second Part
        Container ctrglobalInfosSecondPart= new Container(new BorderLayout());
        if(site.getSiteYou().getPhonepro().trim().length() != 0){
            ctrglobalInfosSecondPart.setUIID("ctrglobalInfosFirstPart");

            Button btnAppeler = new Button("Appeler");
            btnAppeler.setUIID("btnAppelerFichePro");
            btnAppeler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Display.getInstance().dial(site.getSiteYou().getPhonepro());
                }
            });
            ctrglobalInfosSecondPart.add(BorderLayout.EAST,btnAppeler);
        }


        ctrglobalInfosFichePro.add(ctrglobalInfosFirstPart);
        ctrglobalInfosFichePro.add(ctrglobalInfosSecondPart);

        content.add(ctrglobalInfosFichePro);
        /*
         * Building Form
         */
        if(site.getCanaccess()){
            Button btnTakeAppointement = new Button("");
            btnTakeAppointement.setUIID("");
            btnTakeAppointement.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    if(site.getNewcontactblocked()){
                        if(canContactTakeEvent != null && CalendoviaApp.isConnected==1 && CalendoviaApp.customer.getId() != 0){
                            switch(canContactTakeEvent.intValue()){
                            case 0:
                                FicheProCannotTakeEvent ficheProCannotTakeEvent = new FicheProCannotTakeEvent(site, canContactTakeEvent, savedSites, searchWho,true);
                                ficheProCannotTakeEvent.show();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                FicheProRdvSelect ficheProRdvSelect = new FicheProRdvSelect(performances,site, savedSites, searchWho, null);
                                ficheProRdvSelect.show();
                                break;
                            [...]
                            default:
                                FicheProCannotTakeEvent ficheProCannotTakeEvent4 = new FicheProCannotTakeEvent(site, new Long(4), savedSites, searchWho,true);
                                ficheProCannotTakeEvent4.show();
                                break;
                            }
                        }else{
                            FicheProCannotTakeEvent ficheProCannotTakeEvent = new FicheProCannotTakeEvent(site, new Long(0), savedSites, searchWho,false);
                            ficheProCannotTakeEvent.show();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        FicheProRdvSelect ficheProRdvSelect = new FicheProRdvSelect(performances,site, savedSites, searchWho, null);
                        ficheProRdvSelect.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,btnTakeAppointement);
        }else{
            Button btnParrainage = new Button("");
            btnParrainage.setUIID("btnTakeRdvBig");
            btnParrainage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Parrainage parrainage = new Parrainage(site, getComponentForm());
                    parrainage.show();
                }
            });
            addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,btnParrainage);
        }

        addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, ctrPhoto);
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);

    }

}
```

I can't find the error where it happens and why... 
Thanks for your help

Comment: You will need to narrow this down to a more specific section of the code

Comment: I know it's a too much for a code sharing, but that's  the deal, i have no idea about the location of the error :/ I'll try to cut off my code !

Comment: i've edited the code section

Comment: You say "when I try to show my form" so you do have a sense of where this is happening. Does the infinite progress show? What does actually happen? I suggest removing all the code and adding in blocks to narrow down the section. I'm guessing its from something like `getSiteFromId`.

Comment: I've finally find my bug. It's a trim().length() on a null string. Thanks for your help Shai.